# How can I break preg_grep() in PHP?

Tags: php

I have 100 files named: file1, file2,file3... file100. I want to enter only 10 files in Array via preg_grep function, how can I limit the number?

```
$dir=glob('/mydir/*');
preg_grep('#file#i', $dir);
```

I get result array with length 100,how can I divide it before it create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PHP, to get the 1st 10 elements from the $dir array, use `array_slice`.

```
$dir=glob('/mydir/*');

$dir10 = array_slice($dir, 0, 10); 

preg_grep('#file#i', $dir10);
```